# Sending files through Axios to Asp.net Core Api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, react-dropzone

How can I send my files from my javascript(files are through [react dropzone](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/)) to my asp.net core api?

I am using axios and I have something like this

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('folderName', "4141515");
data.append('file', files[0].fileObject); //dropzone wraps the fileobject
axiosInstance2.post("/inventories/ImportImage", data)





[HttpPost("ImportImage")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportImage(IFormFile file, string folderName){}
```

This does work but only the "file" is populated, "foldername" variable is empty.

I tried to put it in a model but it did not work (400 status code)

```
public class Test
{

    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    public string folderName { get; set; }
}
```

Also is FormData the only way to send it to the server?

Edit

Seems like I need to use `[FromForm] Test test`

Comment: I do not know what axios specially do. But for normal jQuery post with FormData, your code should work (folderName will be populated)

Comment: What is your asp.net core version? Did you have `[ApiController]` on the `Controller`? As my test, it is related with `[ApiController]` and here are two options, one is remove `[ApiController]` and another is add `[FromForm]` to specific the binding source for `folderName` like `ImportImage(IFormFile file, [FromForm]string folderName)`

Comment: Using the model is correct, I wold also make sure it's hitting the correct route, and what is causing the 400 code?

Answer (score 0):

With the .net core api controller, you have to use the [FromBody] tag before the parameter, and change the parameter to type Test, it will bind the values to a class that you can use. Like this:
`public async Task ImportImage([FromBody] Test your_values_here){}`